# How to traverse on only a cycle in a graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I'm attempting ch23 in CLRS on MSTs, here's a question:

> Given a graph G and a minimum spanning tree T , suppose that we decrease the weight of one of the edges not in T . Give an algorithm for finding the minimum spanning tree in the modified graph.

A solution I found was to add this new changed edge in `T`, then exactly one simple cycle is created in T, traverse this cycle and delete the max-weight edge in this cycle, *voila*, the new updated MST is found!

My question is, how do I **only** traverse nodes on this simple-cycle? Since DFS/BFS traversals might go out of the cycle if I, say, start the traversal in `T` from one endpoint of this newly added edge in `T`.

One solution I could think of was to find the `biconnected components` in `T` after adding the new edge. Only one `BCC` will be found, which is this newly formed simple-cycle, then I can put in a special condition in my DFS code saying to only traverse edges/nodes in this BCC, and once a back-edge is found, stop the traversal.

Edit: graph G is connected and undirected btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is basically good. To make it more formal you can use [Tarjan's bridge-finding algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_(graph_theory)#Tarjan.27s_Bridge-finding_algorithm)

This algorithm find the cut-edges (aka bridges) in the graph in linear time. Consider `E'` to be the cut-edges set. It is easy to prove that every edge in `E'` can **not** be on circle. So, `E / E'` are must be the cycle in the graph.

You can use hash-map or array build function to find the difference between your `E` and the `cut-edges` set

From here you can run simple for-loop to find the max weight edge which you want to remove.

Hope that help!

Comment: took me long enough to reply, but I see, this is much better, so once a cycle is created, all edges on that cycle will be non-bridges, and all other edges in T are bridges, so I can just find all bridges in T in linear time and then scan them to delete the max-weight bridge, right? I just overcomplicated my initial solution, thanks a lot!